Quartz.NET generates wrong dates by schedule mask
I'm trying to use Quartz.Net CronExpression (Quartz.CronExpression) to get next valid date in valid-datetime sequence by mask:
string mask = "0 15 0 20 2 *";
Quartz.CronExpression cronQuartz = new Quartz.CronExpression(mask);
DateTimeOffset? nextDate = cronQuartz.GetNextValidTimeAfter(new DateTime(2005, 6, 1, 22, 15, 0));
if (nextDate.HasValue) Console.WriteLine(nextDate.Value.LocalDateTime);

I'm expecting '20.02.2006 0:15:00', but Quartz.NET is returning '01.02.2006 0:15:00'
If the mask is "0 15 0 29 2 *" (expects - '29.02.2008 0:15:00'), the result is - '01.02.2006 0:15:00'
What am I doing wrong?

The * should be a ? in your scenario 0 15 0 20 2 ? or 0 15 0 20 2 ? *
? in the 6th position means "no specified value" / any day of the month instead of the * which means every day of the month.
The * 6th parameter "Day of week" means every day of week and is likely overriding your 4th parameter, exactly on the 20th "Day of month"
See Docs: Quartz Cron Expressions

But '20 2' points specifically to February 20. Why doesn't Quartz skip every day of the week until February 20th?

OK thanks. I realized that Quartz has such a strange logic regarding the symbol '*'.

Instead of '*' I need to use '?' (no specific value) in fields 'day-of-month' and 'day-of-week' (Quartz.NET Cron Expressions)
